# How does Cappuccino manages to layout views like in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, layout, cappuccino

How does the layout support of Cappuccino work? For example the centering and the automatik resizing.

Comment: Humm, are we talking about programming and development platforms or hot drinks for cloudy days and cold nights? Sorry just couldn't resist...

Java, Cappuccino and Cocoa what's next?

Comment: Gem, Perl, Ruby, …
A, B, C, D, E, …
Smalltalk, Newspeak, Steptalk, Strongtalk, …
Python, Squirrel, Rhino, …
Ada, Betrand, Claire, …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autoresizing masks are more or less implemented in this method:
http://github.com/280north/cappuccino/blob/master/AppKit/CPView.j#L987

On a more conceptual level, all views in Cappuccino are absolutely positioned. By not relying on the browser to lay things out, we always know exactly where everything is, and can make decisions accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking for an explanation on how to use the feature (one good place is this tutorial: http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/automatic-layout/ ), or are you asking how it is implemented?